# Can't use UDF as constraint in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm running MariaDB 10.3.17 and I'm trying to add a constraint to an existing table. The constraint uses a UDF - [which should be allowed](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/).

Here's my table and UDF.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE real_estate.sample_two_expected_output (
u_id int (9) NOT NULL,
first_date date NOT NULL,
last_date date NOT NULL,
days int AS (DATEDIFF(last_date,first_date)+1),
address varchar(50),
price varchar(50),
--Constraints
CONSTRAINT dates CHECK (last_date >= first_date),
PRIMARY KEY (u_id,first_date));

DELIMITER //
USE real_estate;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION overlap(
    u_id INT,
    first_date DATE,
    last_date DATE
) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE valid INT;
    SET valid = 1; 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM real_estate.sample_two_expected_output t WHERE t.u_id = u_id AND first_date <= t.last_date AND t.first_date <= last_date) THEN SET valid = 0; 
    ELSE SET valid = 1; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN valid;
END; \\
DELIMITER;
```

I try to add this function as a constraint in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE real_estate.sample_two_expected_output ADD CONSTRAINT overlap CHECK(overlap(u_id,first_date,last_date)=1);
```

However I get the below error message and I don't know why.

```
EXECUTE FAIL:

  ALTER TABLE real_estate.sample_two_expected_output ADD CONSTRAINT overlap CHECK(overlap(u_id,first_date,last_date)=1);

Message :

  Function or expression '`overlap`()' cannot be used in the CHECK clause of `overlap`
```

Comment: It looks like `UDFs` and a stored function using `CREATE FUNCTION` are _two entirely different things_, based on their info at [UDFs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-function-udf/#description): `For creating a stored function as opposed to a user-defined function, see CREATE FUNCTION.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use any deterministic user defined function (UDF) but not a stored function (SF) in constraints like `DEFAULT`, `CHECK`, etc.

A big difference between UDFs and SFs is the fact that a UDF is usually written in C/C++ while a SF is written in SQL. That means it is not possible to execute SQL code in a UDF within the same connection, which would lead to significant problems, as your SF shows:

Depending on the storage engine `ALTER TABLE` locks the entire table, parts of it or creates a temporary copy. I cannot imagine a way to execute the SQL statement `SELECT * FROM real_estate.sample_two_expected_output t WHERE t.u_id = u_id ..` in your SF while the table is locked or reorganized.

Comment: Thanks Georg & Paul - I read more about UDF last night and realised my mistake (I was confusing UDF with stored functions).

Comment: [The documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/#check-constraints) says (emphasis mine): "One can use ***most deterministic functions*** in a constraint, ***including*** UDFs." In light of that, why is it that *some* deterministic SQL functions (not UDFs) are permitted (such as many that return `BOOLEAN`), but others aren't?

Comment: Is there a way to make a UDF function deterministic? I have created a C/C++ function and it works when I use `SELECT my_func()`, but when I use it as check constraint in `CREATE TABLE xx ( x TEXT CHECK (my_func()))`I still get the error `Function or expression cannot be used in the CHECK clause`

Comment: @Fredster, the function's behaviour should not depend on variables that are defined/mutable outside the scope of the function.

Comment: What do you mean? The function depends on one input string argument. It outputs a string.